# Removable Checklist Items

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an interactive to do list in which I enter text into a text box, click a button, and it adds the items underneath. So far I have successfully been able to add items to my list using the button but am not able to remove one item at a time by clicking on it, which is what I would like to be able to do. (Ideally each item would have a check box next to it and when I click that the item would disappear). So far, using the .remove() action I have only been able to make ALL of the items in my list disappear by clicking. I did some research and thought that the .on() action may be what I need. I tried it and now I cannot make items disappear at all. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var toAdd=$('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $('#item').append.('.list');
    });
    $(document).on('click','item',function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Is there anything that stands out as being incorrect? Or is there a better way to go about this? I am brand new to this and appreciate any and all feedback.Thank you!

Comment: Show us your HTML code as well. Or better, make a JsFiddle on www.jsfiddle.net and share it here.

Comment: I found a typo and changed 'item' to '.item' and now it makes all of the items in my list disappear instead of just the one I click. It also will not let me add anything else to my list after this. Sorry for all of the reading!

Comment: I'll go to JsFiddle and share what I get

Comment: Here is the link to the JsFiddle page where I put all of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/LC7bH/

Answer (score 1):

I forked your fiddle, with corrected code: http://jsfiddle.net/XEDHJ/2/

Here's where you were having trouble:

```
$('.list').on('click','input',function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Using `on` was the right idea, it's perfect for this situation.  The way you use `on` is that you have a *parent node*, in this case a div with a class of `list`, and a number of matched `child nodes`, in this case any element that is an `input` underneath your parent node.  Child nodes are denoted by the selector in the second argument.  This will match any input node under your div even if they are created after the page is rendered.

Because I wrapped your input in a `<div>` tag, we actually want to remove that parent `<div>`.  So we call `$(this).parent().remove()`.

I left my original example below but this should be sufficient to get you going.

---

It looks like something like this is what you're looking for:

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Khesy/

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#item').append("<div><input name='checkListItem' type='checkbox'></input>To do!</div>");
    });
    $('#item').on('click','input',function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Add Item"></input>
<div id="item">
</div>
```

Comment: What's happening now is that when I click on the text box it just adds a list item called "To Do" with a checkbox next to it. And when I click a check box it deletes the last item, not the item I checked off. Here is my new code: http://jsfiddle.net/LC7bH/6/

Comment: Try the fiddle at the top of my answer

Comment: Thank you so much!This really helped. This is only my second day and I have no idea what I'm doing!